# Chart.js how to reduce labels for xAxes

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am new Chart.js so I have problems.
I want to make a chart type bar for hourly information. But when I want to display information for a week, a month and a long period and I try to reduce the labels for xAxes. In a week I have 168 hours and I want to display only the days when it is 00:00, for that I put empty string on the others but on chart I see "undefined" and not all days are displayed. In the photo, there is information only for 10 hours, the rest  values are 0.
[image]

The problem will become even bigger when it should be for a month or 6 months(where I want to display only first day of week. I will make logic to reduce labels but what to set
in chart xAxes labels to not display "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement `ticks.callback` options in X axis.

See doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

In the callback you can implement the logic you need (as you described above).

Returning `undefined` or empty string from callback, the label is not drawn.